# Can getbuffer access a named buffer from a macro?

Tags: context

I am writing a document where I each section has a dedicated buffer that is called at its beginning. (Not sure this is very clear in English).

To have it automatized, I planned to call one buffer name with a macro, but looks
like `getbuffer` does not like macro substitution. It doesn't work anyway in this MWE

```
\startbuffer [Truite]
Elle nous jouait la truite, la truite de Schubert
\stopbuffer

\starttext

\def\Schubert{Truite}

Comme le disaient les frères Jacques:

\getbuffer[\Schubert{}]

Encore une fois:

\getbuffer[Truite]
\stoptext
```

Is there a way to access named buffer with a macro?

Comment: Use `\getbuffer[\Schubert]` without braces.

Comment: ...or define `\Schubert` to take one argument to get rid of the braces, i.e. `\def\Schubert#1{Truite}`.

Comment: Thank you, deleting the brace solved the problem. Could you post an answer and explain why braces are making such troubles?

Comment: @Henri Meinke. Very interesting. I thought that when calling one argument in a macro, a #1 in the macro definition is required…

Comment: @sztruks Because the argument to `\getbuffer` gets detokenized, i.e. ConTeXt will look for a buffer literally named `Truite{}`.

Comment: @sztruks No, you can always take arguments and not use them.  ConTeXt even has a macro called `\gobbleoneargument` which takes one argument, ignores it and does nothing.  It's mainly useful to implement other macros.  A common idiom is `\ifconditional\somecondition\expandafter\firstofoneargument\else\expandafter\gobbleoneargument\fi`.

Comment: I would be glad to accept an answer from one of you (@Wolfgang Schuster, @Henri Meinke) with those explanations. Might help future researches if someone faces this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to remove the braces `{}` from the argument you pass to the `\getbuffer` command because the end up as part of the name which is used to access the buffer.

```
\startluacode

userdata = userdata or { }

function userdata.argument(str)
    context.quotation(context.nested.type(str))
end

\stopluacode

\def\LuaArgument[#1]%
  {\ctxlua{userdata.argument("#1")}}

\setuptype[space=on]

\starttext

\starttabulate[|lh{\type}|l|]
\HC {\LuaArgument  [Truite]}   \EQ \LuaArgument  [Truite]   \NC\NR
\HC {\LuaArgument  [Truite{}]} \EQ \LuaArgument  [Truite{}] \NC\NR
\HC {\LuaArgument [{Truite}]}  \EQ \LuaArgument [{Truite}]  \NC\NR
\HC {\LuaArgument [{Truite} ]} \EQ \LuaArgument [{Truite} ] \NC\NR
\HC {\LuaArgument[ {Truite}]}  \EQ \LuaArgument[ {Truite}]  \NC\NR
\stoptabulate

\stoptext
```

[image]